# Packaging error trying to run ROS tests from Tox

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run `tox` to run Python tests in my ROS package, I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: ros_qr_tracker/.tox/log/tox-0.log
ERROR: actionid: tox
msg: packaging
cmdargs: ['/usr/bin/python3', local('ros_qr_tracker/setup.py'), 'sdist', '--formats=zip', '--dist-dir', local('ros_qr_tracker/.tox/dist')]
env: None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup
ImportError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'

ERROR: FAIL could not package project - v = InvocationError('/usr/bin/python3 ros_qr_tracker/setup.py sdist --formats=zip --dist-dir ros_qr_tracker/.tox/dist (see ros_qr_tracker/.tox/log/tox-0.log)', 1)
```

My package is for Python 2.7. Why is it trying to run with Python3?

My `setup.py` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def get_reqs(*fns):
    lst = []
    for fn in fns:
        for package in open(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, fn)).readlines():
            package = package.strip()
            if not package:
                continue
            lst.append(package.strip())
    return lst

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=['ros_qr_tracker'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=get_reqs('pip-requirements.txt'),
)

setup(**d)
```

and my `tox.ini` looks like:

```
[tox]
envlist = py{27}
recreate = True

[testenv]
basepython =
    py27: python2.7
deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/pip-requirements.txt
    -r{toxinidir}/pip-requirements-test.txt
commands = nosetests -vv
```

As some other answers have pointed out, I've ensured catkin-pkg is installed by running `sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg` and `dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg` confirms the package was installed into Python2.7's site-packages, so the issue here seems to be that catkin-pkg is using the wrong version of Python. Why is this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284875/packaging-error-trying-to-run-ros-tests-from-tox/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:\

> so the issue here seems to be that catkin-pkg is using the wrong version of Python

`catkin_pkg` is a Python module, so a passive artefact. It cannot "use" a version of Python.

I would check to make sure that `tox` is using / targetting the right Python version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I was using the version of tox in Ubuntu's standard repo package, which is a bit old. I uninstalled this and re-installed the latest from PyPI, and it correctly ran using Python2.7 instead of Python3.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0